# PHP SQL: I cant transfer data from 1 table to another table in database sql using UI button in php file

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to add a personal contact from the general contacts db table

A user will click the EDIT button then they will view the info before deciding to add it into the personal contact.

I think my problem is that my PHP code can't enter the SESSION name of the logged in user in my SQL INSERT INTO Statement.

Here is the SQL code

[WEBPAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUhxi.png)

[PHP CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFUcD.png)

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $user                   = $_POST['u_username']; 
    $contact_username       = $_POST['contact_username'];
    
    
    $savesql2 = "INSERT INTO personal_contacts (id,contact_username, u_username) 
    VALUES ( '$id','$contact_username', '$user')";

    mysqli_query($db, $savesql2); 

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Contact saved"; 
    header('location: index.php');
    

}
```

Comment: Please post code, not images. If you're editing it should be an `update`, not an `insert`, no? I also don't see `$id` being set so that could be an issue. Looks like there isn't error reporting being used.

Comment: yes, i am still a newbie in php coding i'm still learning how to use those

Comment: Also use [prepared statments to avoid SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1066240)

Comment: While developing, always add this to the very top of your script (or config include): `ini_set('display_startup_errors', true); ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, and if working with mysqli, add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`.

Answer (score -1):

Your code

```
$savesql2 = "INSERT INTO personal_contacts (id,contact_username, u_username) 
VALUES ( '$id','$contact_username', '$user')";
```

assumes that there is an `$id`, a `$contact_username` and a `$user` variable. While `$contact_username` and `$user` exists indeed, `$id` is not defined which will lead to troubles. If `$id` is automatically set by your table, then you can do the following:

```
$savesql2 = "INSERT INTO personal_contacts (contact_username, u_username) 
VALUES ( '$contact_username', '$user')";
```

If not, then you will need to properly set `$id` as well.

**IMPORTANT**

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please read about it and refactor your code to make it more secure.

Comment: Can someone point out why this answer has been downvoted? Thanks!